# Java BufferedReader on System.in ignores first line / command

Tags: java, console-application, user-input

I have created a simple console application for java with an JavaBufferedReader to read the commands from the terminal. For some reason the first command issued is always completly ignored. Even while debugging no value gets read and the input String is still not initialized. After issueing a second command the input String gets the value I wrote in the console.

I am using IntelliJ and the integrated terminal with gradle and JDK 11.
I litterly can't see any reason, why the first command is just completly ignored.

```java
BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

And the main shell functionality

```java
 public void runMainLoop() throws IOException {
    boolean quit = false;

    while (!quit) {
      System.out.print("prompt> ");
      final String input = inReader.readLine();   // <-- This input gets no value after pressing "enter". 
      if (input == null) {                        // all other "enter" after the first one are working
        break; 
      }

      try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input)) {
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");

        if (!scanner.hasNext()) {
          printError("No command specified!");
          break;
        }

        switch (scanner.next().toLowerCase()) {

          case "help":
            printHelpMessage();
            break;

          case "quit":
            quit = true;
            println("Terminate...");
            break;

          default:
            printError("Unknown command given.");
            printHelpMessage();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just commenting to say I could not reproduce this with IntelliJ and JDK 15.

Comment: What do mean "no value"?  It has to be something, or do you mean it's NULL?  Are you using the debugger to walk through the code to see what is happening for the first iteration?

Comment: The debugger does not even stop there. It has no value. Not null or anything, just nothing. I am pretty sure, the problem is not in the code. Its probably something configuration related, but I have no clue where the error could be.

Comment: The debugger does not recognize, that I have entered a command. The debugger shows "The application is running". Then I enter a new command and all next commands are working and the debugger stopps after a command is entered. It just does not after the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to apply the divide & conquer debugging strategy: Start with the absolute minimum that works and add parts of the program back until it stops working. Then examine the last added part.

This works for me, so I guess your problem is somewhere else:

```
BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = inReader.readLine();
System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: Yeah I also think, its more a configuration error somewhere, but I have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: I tried to give you a tool to figure out where your problem is.

Comment: I just tested your minimal code. For some reason this does not work for me. I am on a completly new gradle project (Intellij template) with only your provided code. The problem: The terminal never asks me for the input and just runs for ever without doing anything. The debugger also stays in "Application still running" state after it reaches the second line. Never had this behaviour before.

Comment: The divide & conquer approach still applies: Remove / replace IDE's, tools and JDKs until it starts working, then examine the last changed part in your toolchain.

Comment: Yes thank you. I finally figured it out. I have an error in the IntelliJ settings at "Build, Execution, ... > Build Tools > Gradle". I needed to change the "Use Gradle from" to the "gradle-wrapper.properties" file. I needed to change that earlier, because jacoco did not recognize any tests if using this setting. || But on my new bare project it still does not work with this fix. There I needed to change the "Build and run using" (IntelliJ) setting (instead of Gradle [default option]).

Comment: This is still weird on the new project but at least it is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I tested your code in my IntelliJ. When pressing enter with no value as first command, it printed "No command specified!" and for other commands, it printed expected answers based on your switch cases. (As first command and also after the first one)
I mean it worked for me. Please elaborate a little bit more on what goes wrong in your case.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have no idea where the error is. But its for sure not the code. Thats the only thing I know so far. It doesn't work on several of my devices. So I thought at first its a code problem. But now I think its some weird configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, it might be.